# Wire tag vs. wires tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[Wire](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/wire) is useful. "Wires" as a tag is not. I've edited the question that has [wires](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wires) and removed it (admittedly its replacement, [wiring](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring), is [*almost* as bad a choice](http://wiring.org.co/)) but I still can't attach [wire](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire) to [a question about Wire](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/arduino-master-slave-pins). I believe someone may need to nuke [wires](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wires) directly, but is there any way to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one really can nuke [wires](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wires). There is a system background process that is ran daily that cleans up tags without any questions.

- Tag it [wire-library](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire-library) so you can get it past the system (and it's much less ambiguous)

As far as what to do to prevent this from happening, I did this this:

- Synonymize [wires](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wires) ← [wiring](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring), because someone wouldn't type "wiring" when referring to the library. The system will automatically rename everything tagged "wiring" to "wires."

This way, if someone types wires or wiring, they will get wiring. If they type wire, it will have an option for "wire-library" and "wiring." This will fix the problem.

We should leave [wire](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wire) alone. It's way to ambiguous to be synonymized to one of the two types of wire.

Comment: I have tagged the question [tag:wire-library] and have edited the tag to provide some useful information.